# I can't switch pages on the Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have trouble when I want to switch pages on my menu code like this

```
children: <Widget>[
   MenuUtama(Icons.assignment, 'Lihat Nilai', () => Soon()),
   MenuUtama(Icons.credit_card, 'Lihat Pembayaran', () => Soon()),
   MenuUtama(Icons.event, 'Lihat Jadwal', () => {}),
   MenuUtama(Icons.exit_to_app, 'Log Out', () => {}),
]
```

for my structure from this code

```
class MenuUtama extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final Function onTap;
  MenuUtama(this.icon, this.text, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 10.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        shadowColor: Colors.grey,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: onTap,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  icon,
                  size: 75,
                  color: Color(0xffB22222),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Color(0xff4D4D4D)),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to move to the Soon.dart page if I click on one of the menus, and the plan for each menu is to move to its own page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure of your app structure but i think what you need to use is the [Navigator](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics).

```
MenuUtama(Icons.assignment, 'Lihat Nilai',
() => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context){
                              return Soon();
                            }
                        ))),
```

That is if you want to naviagate to your new Screen `Soon`

Answer (score 0):

In order to navigate to a new screen, you can use code like this:

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Soon()),
  );
}
```

There are also other ways to achieve this, like named routes. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes